# Fragments not loading in my project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am working with ViewPager with Circle Page Indicator.

And I am following this [link for sample](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/)

Here in below I mentioned my class details.[image: Folder Structure]

**HelpScreen.java**

```
This Activity had one fragment called HelpScreenFragment.java

    public class HelpScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help_screen);

        HelpScreenFragment helpScreenFragment = new HelpScreenFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_helpscreen_container,
                        helpScreenFragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.help_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**help_screen.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frame_helpscreen_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SlidePagerAdapter.java**
 This class extends PagerAdapter and used to inflate the

```
    public class SlidePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    ImageView helpScreenImage;
    List<Integer> drawableBitmap;
    int gallery_grid_Images[] = { R.drawable.sample1, R.drawable.sample2,
            R.drawable.sample3, R.drawable.sample4, R.drawable.sample5, };

    private Context mContext;

    Activity activity;

    public SlidePagerAdapter(Activity mContext) {
        super();
        this.activity = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, container,
                false);
        helpScreenImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.helpscreen_image);
        helpScreenImage.setImageResource(gallery_grid_Images[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(helpScreenImage);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

}
```

**viewpager_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/helpscreen_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**HelpScreenFragment.java**

```
public class HelpScreenFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager helpScreenPager;

CirclePageIndicator mCirclePageIndicator;

SlidePagerAdapter mSlidePagerAdapter;

Activity activity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.helpscreen_fragment, container,
            false);

    initializeWidgets(view);


    mSlidePagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(activity);

    helpScreenPager.setAdapter(mSlidePagerAdapter);
    mCirclePageIndicator.setViewPager(helpScreenPager);

    return view;

}

private void initializeWidgets(View view) {

    helpScreenPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mCirclePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view
            .findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

And in helpscreen_fragment.xml contains only ViewPager and CirclePageIndicator

**helpscreen_fragment.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.viewpagerdemo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!--
         <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/helpscreen_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.example.viewpagerdemo.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_pager"
        android:padding="10dip" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When executing the project I am getting only blank screen. 
What I did wrong? What changes have to made.
Could anybody help on this?

```
  [1]: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSold.jpg
```

Comment: where is `HelpScreenFragment` class code?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Hi added that Fragment class code. Thank you for your kind support.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Ve : have you tried my answer?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes tried. Working. But crashing at some point. Error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: no need to use `((ViewPager) container).addView(helpScreenImage);` line

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have removed the code. But select indication animation not smoothy and image not displayed. Before its smoothy but crashed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70630/discussion-between-karthikeyan-ve-and--k).

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The imageview not set with images from drawble. In that adapter class I am returning a view.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I missed the container.addView(view); Now solved. Its working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
   @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

Currently `getCount` method of `SlidePagerAdapter`  retuning `0` so no item is visible in ViewPager. return `gallery_grid_Images` array size from getCount() :

```
   @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gallery_grid_Images.length;
    }
```